# What does pe_size of sysptnext in Informix mean?

Tags: informix

What does `pe_size` of `sysptnext` in Informix mean,
and what is unit of `pe_size`?  Is the unit o/s specific?
Can `pe_size` be used for calculating the size of a table, such as:

```
select dbsname, tabname, sum(pe_size )*2 / 1024 total_size 
from systabnames, sysptnext where partnum = pe_partnum 
group by 1, 2 order by 3 desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query shown is running against the tables in the `sysmaster` database.  You can normally find a description of the tables and views in `sysmaster` in the Informix Aministrator's Reference manual.  However, it seems that `sysptnext` (`ptn` = partition, `ext` = extents) is not documented.  This means it is used in some views.  You can find out more, including the comment '{ Internal Use Only }', in the `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/sysmaster.sql` table.  The comment mainly means that Informix doesn't promise not to change the table when it needs to.  It won't normally change the views that use the table, but it might modify the table without notice.

```
{ Partition Extent Descriptions }
    create table informix.sysptnext     { Internal Use Only     }    
    (    
    pe_partnum  integer,    { partnum for this partition    }    
    pe_extnum   smallint,   { extent number         }    
    pe_chunk    integer,    { chunk number for this extent  }
    pe_offset   integer,    { chunk offset for this extent  }
    pe_size     integer,    { size of this extent       }    
    pe_log      integer     { logical page for start    }    
    );
```

Extent sizes internally are in pages (for all you specify them in kibibytes (kilobytes) when you create a table).  The page size depends on the dbspace that is storing the table.  However, unless you've configured different dbspaces with different page sizes, the same size is used everywhere.  It is platform specific whether the page size is 2 KiB (Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, Linux) or 4 KiB (Windows, Mac OS X).

Your query should get close to producing a size for the table in terms of allocated space.  This is larger than the space used to store rows.  It also doesn't account for blobs stored in blob spaces or smart blob spaces; it also doesn't account for (detached) indexes.  And, as mentioned earlier, it assumes a page size of 2 KiB rather than adapting to different page sizes.  The division by 1024 produces a size in MiB (mebibytes; the binary equivalent of a megabyte).

I reserve the right to have missed something about fragmented tables.  A fragmented table has multiple partitions, but the `systabnames` table and your grouping clauses should deal with that.

If you have a MODE ANSI database, you might have two (or more) different tables with the same name but different owners; your query would conflate those tables into one reported answer.

Comment: so,if I want a query that will list all tables and its size（really size in disk）,what would it be ?@Jonathan Leffler